# cuDNN kernel criteria for LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am attempting to train an LSTM generative model by using the cuDNN kernel to speed up the process, yet it seems that my model falls outside of the criteria.
I am having trouble understanding what is the issue exactly.

Here is the warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
```

And here is my generative model:

```
def build_generative_model(vocab_size, embed_dim, lstm_units, lstm_layers, batch_size, dropout=0):
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]))

for i in range(max(1, lstm_layers)):
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size))

return model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, I feel so fing stupid hahaha.
For anyone having this issue, look over the requirements: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM
Go slowly through each one and set your layers to the appropriate values, in my case

```
recurrent_dropout = 0
```

instead of

```
recurrent_dropout = 0.0
```